# ¿Cómo hacer auto scroll hasta el ultimo elemento en un grid?

Tags: genexus, grid

Primero un amable saludo a la comunidad.

Intento programar un chat en Genexus para smart devices con el generador .net.

En un SDPanel tengo un Grid y un botón "insert" para insertar texto dentro del Grid. Quisiera que se desplazara hasta el último elemento del Grid al insertar un nuevo elemento. Intenté utilizar lo siguiente.

```
grid.Select(&ultiElement)
```

Cómo el Grid al entrar en la pantalla no carga con todos los elementos, esta función no hace nada porque no encuentra el item pues no está cargado, si me desplazo manualmente (con el dedo) hasta el último elemento y luego inserto un nuevo texto con el botón tampoco realiza la acción de desplazamiento al último elemento.

```
Event boton.Tap
  composite
    
    &mensage.ReporteId = &Reporte
    &mensage.MensajeTexto = &texto
    &mensage.Save()

    &texto.SetEmpty()       
    &ultiElement = CantidadMensajes(&reporte)   
    grid.Select(&ultiElement)
    
  endcomposite
Endevent
```

Pero sí y solo sí agrego el código `msg(&ultiElement.toString)` antes de línea `grid.Select(&ultiElement)` si funciona o_O, aunque no todas las veces.

A manera de prueba en un botón aparte hice lo siguiente.

```
Event desplaza.Tap
   grid.Select(&ultiElement)
Endevent
```

Este desplazamiento funciona todas las veces, siempre y cuando ya se hayan cargado todos los elementos del grid, si no la aplicación crashea.

¿Existe alguna manera de programar este comportamiento? Tengo entendido que se puede programar en csharp en los eventos pero no sé cómo, ¿Es posible cargar todos los elementos del Grid al entrar en la pantalla?, ¿Es posible utilizar un SDT para hacer el chat?

Gracias.

Comment: Como estas? No te serviria utilizar la propiedad "inverse loading" del grid? Precisamente esta heacha para el caso canonico de los chats. Aca tenes link a la docum: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?32660,Inverse%20Loading%20property

Comment: Voy a estudiar el tema, gracias por el enlace.

Comment: @chona, seguí el documento, hice el grid basado únicamente en la transacción, pero a veces se desplaza y otras veces no, abra una manera de mejorar esto?

Comment: Si seguiste bien la docum deberia funcionarte. Capaz lo mejor es que te contactes directo con soporte genexus para consultarles por este caso.

Comment: @Chona muchas gracias pude solucionarlo y es muy sencillo, además de realizar los pasos de la documentación también  se debe configurar la propiedad order, les dejo el enlace a todo el que quiera realizar esta misma implementación, [1]: https://youtu.be/wxV-0IajS3o?t=159.

Answer (score 1):

La solución es muy sencilla, además activar la carga inversa se debe configurar la propiedad order, les dejo el enlace a todo el que quiera realizar esta misma implementación.

https://youtu.be/wxV-0IajS3o?t=159

Agradezco al admin por este bonito site y a @Chona por su tiempo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.